# How to write MongoDB Collection Filters for Child/Nested Objects in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

How to write MongoDB Collection Filters for Child/Nested Objects in Java?

Hi I am new to Mongo DB, can someone please help on this?

My MongoDB has collections of data as mentioned below. And I need to filter the collection using com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.
Can someone please let me know the syntax in Java, how filtering will look for such cases?

mytobecompare Java Object also have same struture.

Bson queryParams = Filters.and(
 Filters.eq("my_data.count", mytobecompare.getCount()), //The filter for Count is okay.
 But what will be the Filters for "myslot" data structure that has list of objects(length and value).
 And I need to match all the collection data that has count 4, and myslot:[{length:1,value:A},{length:2,value:B},{length:3,value:C},{length:4,value:D}]

```
"my_data" : {
    "count" : "4",
    "myslot" : [
        {
            "length" : 1,
            "value" : "A"
        },
        {
            "length" : 2,
            "value" : "B"
        },
        {
            "length" : 3,
            "value" : "C"
        },
        {
            "length" : 4,
            "value" : "D"
        }       
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the criteria for the nested list ?

Comment: I just want to compare and filter out "my_data" collections with same "count" and "myslot"  with same length and value list. Please let me know if it clarifies your Criteria query.

Comment: so in essence you are just comparing the whole document ? Something like `Filters.eq("my_data", mytobecompare)` ?

Comment: Thanks Veeram for replying. Actually not complete data.Have given a portion of the object. the "my_data" resides within another root level like "my_root_data". But from your comments it seems we can use the complete Filters.eq("my_data", mytobecompare), but will it be able to compare with the complete java Object mytobecompare?

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the sample code:

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

```
 private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

public static <T> String convertObjectToJSON(final T messageObject) {
    try {
        return OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(messageObject);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
}
```

................................................................................... 
    Filters.eq("my_data",  Document.parse(convertObjectToJSON(mytobecompare.getMyslotData()))))